# SQLBulkCopy Row Count When Complete

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am using SQLBulkCopy to move large amounts of data.  I implemented the notification event to notify me every time a certain number of rows have been processed, but the OnSqlRowsCopied event does not fire when the job is completed.  How do I get the total number of rows copied when the SQLBulkCopy writetoserver completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to run a COUNT() query on the table after finishing, as in the MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.close.aspx).

Other than that, can't you tell up front? e.g. if you're passing a DataTable to WriteToServer() then you know how many records by doing a .Rows.Count on it.

Comment: and if you are using an IDataReader you can just wrap it, there should never really be a need to call count but its a hack that can work

Comment: @Sam, How do you mean "wrap it"?  I have a `SqlDataReader`, and the closest thing to a row count it has is the `RecordsAffected` property which is always -1 in this case...

Comment: This is the safer method than the ones listed below (which are, admittedly, slick!) -- accessing a private field could break in the future without warning (Microsoft could change the implementation of a public API without breaking the public API by changing field names), but the count query would still work.

Comment: @AriRoth We get it, people got to stop commenting that on every reflection solution. It's still safer than using count() for many reasons (maybe the table was already populated before, maybe we didn't copy all rows from the source, maybe it's just a long table and count() would take a long time...)

Answer (score 35):

The following hack (using reflection) is an option:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class to process the SqlBulkCopy class
    /// </summary>
    static class SqlBulkCopyHelper
    {
        static FieldInfo rowsCopiedField = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the rows copied from the specified SqlBulkCopy object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bulkCopy">The bulk copy.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int GetRowsCopied(SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy)
        {
            if (rowsCopiedField == null)
            {
                rowsCopiedField = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_rowsCopied", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
            }

            return (int)rowsCopiedField.GetValue(bulkCopy);
        }
    }
```

And then use the class as follows:

```
int rowsCopied = SqlBulkCopyHelper.GetRowsCopied(bulkCopyObjectInYourCode);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not make it an extension method?  public static int GetRowsCopied(this SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy)

Comment: My only concern here is that it gets an internal field and doesn't play with the public API.  That internal field could change in a future implementation without breaking the API, and that would break this code.  (It may be unlikely, but it is possible, and I've seen stuff like that happen before.)  It's kind of dangerous to be accessing private fields for exactly this reason -- it might work today, but there's no guarantee it will work tomorrow.  (Really, it would have been nice if Microsoft had just exposed a public property here.)

Comment: Strange that it's an int while it's a long in the event args. I wonder what happens if you copy >int.max rows.

Comment: Warning: this internal implementation detail just changed in SqlClient 5.2.0!

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I did -- it's a slight modification of [Rahul Modi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303051) in this thread (basically it just puts the SqlRowsCopied event inline, which I think is a bit cleaner in this instance than creating the new event handler method):

```
private long InsetData(DataTable dataTable, SqlConnection connection)
{
   using (SqlBulkCopy copier = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
   {
      var filesInserted = 0L;

      connection.Open();

      copier.DestinationTableName = "dbo.MyTable";
      copier.NotifyAfter = dataTable.Rows.Count;
      copier.SqlRowsCopied += (s, e) => filesInserted = e.RowsCopied;
      copier.WriteToServer(dataTable);

      connection.Close();

      return filesInserted;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For completeness I have implemented as an extension method and included the namespace. Copy and paste this class if you want a fast solution to get the copied count. Note: This count does not take into consideration the number of rows actually inserted when Ignore Duplicates is set to ON.

```
namespace System.Data.SqlClient
{    
    using Reflection;

    public static class SqlBulkCopyExtension
    {
        const String _rowsCopiedFieldName = "_rowsCopied";
        static FieldInfo _rowsCopiedField = null;

        public static int RowsCopiedCount(this SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy)
        {
            if (_rowsCopiedField == null) _rowsCopiedField = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField(_rowsCopiedFieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);            
            return (int)_rowsCopiedField.GetValue(bulkCopy);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `NotifyAfter` to 1. In the handler for `SqlRowsCopied`, increment a counter. After `WriteToServer` completes, read the counter.

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland High Five!

Answer (score 4):

By using `SqlBulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied Event` (Occurs every time that the number of rows specified by the `NotifyAfter` property has been processed) we can achieve SQLBulkCopy Row Count When Complete.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(db.Database.Connection as SqlConnection))
{
  s.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(sqlBulk_SqlRowsCopied);
  s.BatchSize = csvFileData.Rows.Count;//DataTable
  s.NotifyAfter = csvFileData.Rows.Count;
  foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
     s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
  // Set the timeout.
  s.BulkCopyTimeout = 60;
  s.DestinationTableName = "Employee_Data";
  s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
}

private static void sqlBulk_SqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
{
    long Count = e.RowsCopied;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension method:

(Based on [Benzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474394/2060966))

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using static System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class SqlBulkCopyExtensions
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<FieldInfo> _rowsCopiedLazy = new Lazy<FieldInfo>(()
            => typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_rowsCopied", NonPublic | GetField | Instance));

        public static int GetRowsCopied(this SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy)
            => (int)_rowsCopiedLazy.Value.GetValue(sqlBulkCopy);
    }
}
```

Tested & works as of .NET 4.6.1

Note that the field's type is `int` (while the property's type in the event args is `long`). Not sure what happens if you copy > `int.MaxValue` rows.

Comment: Big up and thank you, @marsze & @benzi! This worked like a charm using `sqlBulkCopyObject.GetRowsCopied()`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get row count from SqlBulkCopy, it's important that you set NotifyAfter to 1:

```csharp
var rowsInserted = 0L;
using var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
sbc.NotifyAfter = 1;
sbc.SqlRowsCopied += (s, e) => rowsInserted = e.RowsCopied;
sbc.WriteToServer(dr);
//Get row count
return rowsInserted;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [SqlClient 5.2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/releases/tag/V5.2.0), the internal field `_rowsCopied` has [changed to a long](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/pull/2004).

The good news is that this was done to render the reflection-based hackery unnecessary.  You can now retrieve the number of rows copied via a public, documented API: [`SqlBulkCopy.RowsCopied64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.rowscopied64).

No more need for unsupported reflection hacks!