# Unable to get updated value from method of other class

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

Below is my class:

**MsSql.cs:**

```
public class MSSqlBLL
{
    public static long RowsCopied { get; set; }

    public long BulkCopy()
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Table1";
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
            bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied +=
                new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
            bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 100;
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);

            }
            return RowsCopied;
        }
    }

    private static void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
    {
        RowsCopied = RowsCopied + e.RowsCopied;
    }
}
```

I am calling BulkCopy function from this class and i want to get currently processed record in my affected records variable.

**For eg** :For each iteration of loop i would like to get affected records in my affectedRows variable.

```
public class MySqlBLL
{
    public void GetTotalRows()
        {
            int  totalRecords = 500;
            var table = "Table1";
            for (int i = 0; i < totalRecords / 100; i++) //
             {
                     query = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " LIMIT " + 0 + "," + 100;
                     var reader = Execute(conn, query);
                     long affectedRecords = msSql.BulkCopy();
                     reader.Close();
             }
        }
}
```

In the above method i am sending chunk by chunk data to BulkCopy method to perform bulk copy but for each bulk copy i would like to get number of records that are processed by bulk copy **but the problem is i am getting 0 in affectedRecords variable.**

I want to get access current rows processed by sql bulk copy.

Answer (score 2):

The RowsCopied property is only updated after 100 records are copied (as set using NotifyAfter). If you place

```
Console.WriteLine("Copied {0} so far...", e.RowsCopied);
```

in OnSqlRowsCopied event handler you will get ongoing progress in case of Console app.
But in your case you can simply select count(*) from source table to show the count.

-[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry but i dont want to fire an extra query to get count because in that case i will have to fire query on each iteration

Comment: In simple terms you want the affectedRecords which will be only available after operation is completed so you have wait for it.
`msSql.BulkCopy()
int tries=5;
While(MSSqlBLL.RowsCopied=100 && tries<5)
{
  tries++;
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
long affectedRecords =MSSqlBLL.RowsCopied;
`

Comment: A reference regarding same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188384/sqlbulkcopy-row-count-when-complete)