# About SqlBulkCopy rows copied count (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

The reflection method mentioned here:
[SQLBulkCopy Row Count When Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188384/sqlbulkcopy-row-count-when-complete)
works well. However, since the max value of an int is 2,147,483,647, how to deal with more than the number of rows?

Comment: use a long to get upto 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: you can also use  [Big integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numeric.biginteger.aspx) to store the data.

Comment: Thank @SurajS and Tejinder Singh. A long is more than enough. I will try it out.